# Locked myself out of root access

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, dedicated-server

I'm very new to owning a dedicated server. I'm learning and was configuring one I bought with OVH. I was configuring what I thought was other SHH users.

It was a sshd_config. I appended this to the very bottom of the file:

```
Port 24
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers zax
```

After that I logged off putty and WinSCP and attempted to log back into the servver. It was giving me denied access.

I know OVH is a budget provider, and I attempted to ask them support and they replied as the only option is to  re-install the OS.

I'm totally fine with, because I didn't do much with the OS but I'd rather still want to make sure if theres any other option to get back into the OS. So my question is: Is there any other way to get back into the OS?

If it is the only option, what do I input into the following options to re-install an OS?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgOlw.png

It's a 64-bit Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Did you restart sshd? If not, ssh is going to accept connections on your previous port.

Comment: If you restarted `sshd`, did you tell WinSCP/Putty to use port 24 in the first place?

Comment: Is port 24 blocked in a firewall?

Comment: Yes, I restarted sshd. And I tried port 22-24

Answer (score 3):

OVH offers a Serial-over-LAN option you can use to login to your dedicated server as if you had a keyboard and monitor directly connected to it. Since this login does not go through SSH, you won't be constrained by the options you set.

[OVH Serial-over-LAN Product Description](http://www.ovh.co.uk/dedicated_servers/serial_over_lan.xml)